# Buildozer spec file not allowing me to use python re library

Tags: kivy, specifications, requirements, buildozer

[image]

In the Buildozer spec file under requirements i have to list all library's my program needs. I keep getting the same error when I list the `re` library. Can somebody please help?

```
requirements = kivy,requests,openssl,re
```

Answer (score 2):

p4a/buildozer already packages `python`(2 or 3) and with it every library that's built-in in python. That means every part of the standard library. I don't recall any stripping of python libs, so...

Python is necessary for Kivy to run, therefore `requirements = kivy` should already satisfy the requirement for `<insert any python built-in library here>`.

When a pure-python library is requested through pip, it searches pypi and that `re` seems to return [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/re) which doesn't seem to have any `.zip` or tarball so I don't think you will install it even with basic `pip install re`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect answer! I took the re out and everything worked fine, i did not lose the regex functionality in my final app.